# MVC individual user accounts with OpenId option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, openid-connect

I have an MVC 5 application and I want to allow external users to create an account and log in.
In addition I want the application to be available to employees without creating an account.
To attempt this I setup the mvc site to user Individual User Accounts.
I also added code in the Startup.Auth to allow for OpenId Connect tokens.

The issue is that if I leave the OpenId code in the startup then the authentication defaults to that. I want all users to get to the Account/Login page first and then give the employees the option to use OpenId.

The out of the box templates allows for additional login options for External types to be displayed in the Login view via the _ExternalLoginsListPartial but the OpenId Connection is not listed there.

The authority for the OpenId token is our on site ADFS server.

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                MetadataAddress = metadataAddress,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                //PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all I needed to do was to put the  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication code before the other authentication options. This allows the Account/Login form to be displayed by default and also displays the OpenId button to allow that option.

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
         new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
         {
             ClientId = clientId,
             MetadataAddress = metadataAddress,
             RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                //PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);


    }
```